# What's the connection between Mr. Nancy and fried chicken?

Tags: dialogue, american-gods

In *American Gods* season 2 there was a scene where Nancy and Mr. Wednesday were both on a car, between them was a bucket of chicken which Nancy mutters to himself

> This m***f*** asks me if I want something to eat, and then he gets in the car with a bucket of fried f***ing chicken!!

then tosses it out of the window.

That part I don't get, is there something between Nancy and chicken?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This, like many things in the show, is a reference to American culture, which might be why you didn't completely get it immediately.

Eating **fried chicken is pretty much a [racial stereotype for African Americans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fried_chicken#Racial_stereotype)** for various reasons, apparently stemming back to the Civil War and to slavery. Now add to this that Mr. Nancy, or Anansi, **as an African god has come to be a representative for the suppressed black community** in America in the show, as he also expresses very often himself.

So for Wednesday to get Nancy fried chicken above everything else is either a direct insult, insensitivity, or a total coincidence. But no matter the reason, it's an offense to Mr. Nancy and a joke fitting to the many references to American culture throughout the show.

You could even go further than being a simple joke with this. While Mr. Nancy only makes a short appearance in season 1 (albeit also in a slavery context), **season 2 puts a lot more emphasis on the racial issues within American society and Nancy's role therein**. In fact, the season so far seems to show that Nancy is trying to rally up the other African gods in order to get his *own* fight going for the cause of the suppressed African Americans that he understands as his followers and feels responsible to care for.

So this fried chicken thing might just be another incident showing that Wednesday isn't taking him serious and might just be using him. It **shows Mr. Nancy yet again that Wednesday ultimately might not be fighting for what *he* feels worth fighting** for and that he might have to go his own way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92792/discussion-on-answer-by-napoleon-wilson-whats-the-connection-between-mr-nancy).

Answer (score 9):

It's related to the stereotype that [African Americans love fried chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotypes_of_African_Americans#Fried_chicken).

> It is a commonly held stereotype that African Americans love fried chicken, which race and folklore professor Claire Schmidt attributes both to its popularity in Southern cuisine and to a scene from the film Birth of a Nation, in which a rowdy African-American man is seen eating fried chicken in a legislative hall. The stereotype is occasionally portrayed as "chicken and waffles".

And since Nancy in the show is one African American God and one that protects the African Americans, Mr. Wednesday assumes by the stereotype that Nancy likes fried chicken.